# Hadoop stream sorting

Tags: sorting, hadoop, streaming

Could anyone help on this hadoop streaming sort problem? Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

I am newbie on Hadoop and need to implement a sort function on a 500GB tab delimited text file. The following is an example input, there are 3 fields in one line like `READA14 chr14   50989`. Here I need to numeric sort by the 2nd and 3rd column, unless I set number of reducers to 1, I will never get the correct ordering result.

Example Input:

---

```
READA14 chr14   50989
READB18 chr18   517043
READC22 chr22   88345
READD10 chr10   994183
READE19 chr19   232453
READF20 chr20   42912
READF9  chr9    767396
READG22 chr22   783469
READG16 chr16   522257
READH9  chr9    826357
READH16 chr16   555098
READH21 chr21   128309
READH4  chr4    719890
READH18 chr18   944551
READH22 chr22   530068
READH9  chr9    212247
READH11 chr11   574930
READH22 chr22   664833
READH2  chr2    908178
READH22 chr22   486178
READH7  chr7    533343
READH6  chr6    109022
READH15 chr15   316353
READH20 chr20   439938
READH21 chr21   731912
READH11 chr11   81162
READH2  chr2    670838
READH15 chr15   729549
READH3  chr3    196626
READH14 chr14   841104
```

---

My code of streaming sort:

---

```
hadoop jar \
/home/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u5.jar \
-input /user/luoqin/projects/samsort/number \
-output /user/luoqin/projects/samsort/number_sort \
-mapper "cat" \
-reducer "sort -k 2.5 -n -k 3" \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner \
-jobconf map.output.key.field.separa="\t" \
-jobconf num.key.fields.for.partition=1 \
-jobconf mapred.data.field.separator="\t" \
-jobconf map.output.key.value.fields.spec="2:0-" \
-jobconf reduce.output.key.value.fields.spec="2:0-" \
-jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=50
```

---

Results were partitioned into 50 parts cause reduce.task is set to 50. Viewing the results as, however it was not correct unless reduce.task is set to 1:

---

```
   hadoop fs -cat /user/projects/samsort/number_sort/*
```

---

Answer (score 0):

BY default hadoop uses a hash partitioner - in that the key output from your mapper 'hashed' to determine which reducer that key should be sent to. This hashing is what's causing your 'incorrect' results when you use more than a single reducer.

You should note that each output part is sorted, and now you just need to interleave the different parts to get your single sorted output.

You can solve this problem by implementing your own partitioner and sending key,value pairs to a reducer depending on the `chrx` value in your second field. You will however need couple your partitioner implementation and the number of reducers, otherwise you'll still similar to results to what you have at the moment.

So if you know the domain or range of values of your second column (lets say `chr0` to `chr255`) then you could run a 256 reducer job with a custom partitioner based upon the int value after the `chr` string